Maven Multiple Repository Issue
I am trying to configure Maven settings.xml file and the project's pom.xml. The gist of my pom.xml currently looks like:
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.cmsk.vod</groupId>
    <artifactId>vod-parent</artifactId>
    <version>8.0.2-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <name>vod-parent</name>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.cmsk.cdparent</groupId>
        <artifactId>oparent</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <modules>
        <module>.....</module>
        <module>.....</module>
        <module>.....</module>
        <module>......</module>
    </modules>
    .
    .
    .
    .
</project>

Now my profile settings in the settings.xml file is something like:
<profiles>

    <profile>
        <id>jfrog</id>
        <!-- Enable snapshots for the built in central repo to direct -->
        <!-- all requests to nexus via the mirror -->
        <repositories>
            
            <repository>
                <id>public</id>
                <url>URL1</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            
            <repository>
                <id>releases</id>
                <url>URL2</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            
            <repository>
                <id>snapshots</id>
                <url>URL3</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            
            <repository>
                <id>cmsk</id>
                <url>URL4</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>
            
        </repositories>
        
        <pluginRepositories>
        
            <pluginRepository>
                <id>central</id>
                <url>URL1</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </pluginRepository>
            
        </pluginRepositories>
        
    </profile>      
    
    <profile>       
        <id>cmsk-public</id>            
        <repositories>          
            <repository>
                <id>cmsk-public</id>
                <name>cmsk-public</name>
                <url>URL5</url>
                <releases>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </releases>
                <snapshots>
                    <enabled>true</enabled>
                    <updatePolicy>always</updatePolicy>
                </snapshots>
            </repository>               
        </repositories>         
    </profile>
    
</profiles>

The issue that i am getting is that org.cmsk.cdparent exists in the repository cmsk-public- profile and not in the jfrog profile.
But when I run mvn clean deploy or install, it just fails at the first attempt looking for the artifact in the jfrog profile URLs.
The stack trace looks like this:
[INFO] Error stacktraces are turned on.
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
Downloading from public: URL1/org/cmsk/cdparent/oparent/2.1.0/oparent-2.1.0.pom
Downloading from releases: URL2/org/cmsk/cdparent/oparent/2.1.0/oparent-2.1.0.pom
Downloading from snapshots: URL3/org/cmsk/cdparent/oparent/2.1.0/oparent-2.1.0.pom
Downloading from cmsk: URL4/org/cmsk/cdparent/oparent/2.1.0/oparent-2.1.0.pom
[ERROR] [ERROR] Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.cmsk.vod:vod-parent:8.0.2-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.cmsk.cdparent:oparent:pom:2.1.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.cmsk.cdparent:oparent:pom:2.1.0 from/to public (URL1): status code: 401, reason phrase:  (401) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 13
 @
[ERROR] The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.project.ProjectBuildingException: Some problems were encountered while processing the POMs:
[FATAL] Non-resolvable parent POM for org.cmsk.vod:vod-parent:8.0.2-SNAPSHOT: The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.cmsk.cdparent:oparent:pom:2.1.0 (absent): Could not transfer artifact org.cmsk.cdparent:oparent:pom:2.1.0 from/to public (URL1): status code: 401, reason phrase:  (401) and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 9, column 13

Sorry I couldn't post the full URLs, privacy thing.
Any pointers would be helpful. I hope i was able to explain the issue clearly.

I see issues: status code: 401, reason phrase:??

@khmarbaise... it is not supposed to be in URL1, it is supposed to be in URL4. That is the doubt. How do i make maven look for artifacts in the URL they are in and not fail when they cant it in the URL they are not supposed to be in.
